# Is it possible to execute Azure PowerShell scripts from an ASP MVC project?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, powershell, azure

I'm new using ASP.Net **MVC**, so i'm doing an auto-training in order to develop a web portal for an intranet that can receive request from users to deploy Virtual Machines from Azure, the request is received by an administrator who can run a script from the portal to create the Virtual Machine.

For example, The idea is to store the scripts in a database, so when the administrator do the action to create the "virtual Machine 01" (he have limited option of Virtual Machines configurations to create), the software run the script "01" store on the database.

That is possible? I hope I have explained the idea well.

Also, if that is possible, can I also show the possibles error messages is something wrong happened?.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Powershell, why not manage it directly from your .NET code?

Azure provides API's that can be called from .NET.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/api/

You'd probably want to look at their Compute Management API for handling virtual machines.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/api/management-compute-sdk-net/

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the ideas, I will check the info, looks interesting and useful.

Using PowerShell is because that was requested, but could raise the idea of using Azure API.